# what does と mean here

Tags: particle-と

> 文字は、言語**と**直接結び付いて意味を表すものであり、その結び付いた意味によって字種に分類される。

I have a rough understanding of the first sentence, but the usage of 「と」 here goes beyond me. Does it mean "and" or "to" here?

Answer (score 2):

It means "with" here (you could probably think of it as a subset of the "and" meaning), and "connected with" can also be expressed as "connected to" or some other variation.

Check ALC for [some examples](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A8%E7%B5%90%E3%81%B3).